# Launch Chrome with JS scripts suspended at startup

Tags: google-chrome, debugging, breakpoints

In NodeJS, you can run a script with the `--debug-brk` option, which pauses your script at the first line. You can then attach with a debugger and resume, ensuring you can hit any breakpoint no matter how early it is in your script.

Is there something similar in Chrome / Chrome Debugging Protocol?

I use an external debugger to debug JS in Chrome. Chrome is launched via command-line, with remote debugging enabled, pointing to a local server with my website / app. Once Chrome is launched, the debugger attaches to the page, but that takes time - by the time the debugger is attached, the scripts have pretty much already executed, meaning I cannot hit breakpoints that are early in the website / app's life cycle.

I thought of adding `debugger;` statements at the beginning of every script, but that would be annoying over time. I also think that the Chrome dev tools need to be open for `debugger;` statements to actually pause, so that might not even work.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In Chrome DevTools, you can use 'Event Listener Breakpoints' to force the execution to pause on 'Script First Statement'. There are others, such as `load`, which happens a little later on. You can then resume execution until the relevant breakpoints should be hit.

[image: Event Listener Breakpoints]

Comment: Do you know if there is a way to control this checkbox from command-line arguments when launching Chrome, or perhaps via a Chrome Debugging Protocol message? Because I'm using an external debugger, I would need to somehow be able to enable that checkbox from outside the Chrome dev tools

Comment: The checked setting is persisted until you uncheck it. I don't know your setup but say you had a Chrome host running on one computer with the `--remote-debugging-port` flag set and you open your app, then on another computer you open Chrome, navigating to the host:port address, and select the tab. If you set the Event Listener Breakpoint on the client and then refresh the app on the host, it should break on the client. If you are using another debugger, using the /JSON end-point, then I guess it's up to that debugging client to have the ability to pause on the first script?

Comment: Interesting, then it should mean that there is a way to set that Event Listener breakpoint remotely, because in your example, the "client" Chrome needs some way to notify the "host" Chrome that it should pause on that event.

After quickly looking at the Chrome Debugging Protocol I can't seem to find something related to that, but there has to be a way... I'll keep looking

Comment: You may be able to find something in the [Debugger Protocol Viewer](https://chromedevtools.github.io/debugger-protocol-viewer/1-1/Debugger/). I haven't tested with [Remote Debugging](https://developer.chrome.com/devtools/docs/debugger-protocol#remote), so I could be wrong.

Comment: Found it! This is the Chrome Debug Protocol message that is sent by the "client" Chrome when you tick the checkbox (ignore the `id`, which is probably just a session-specific ID for the message):
`{ id: 101, method: "DOMDebugger.setInstrumentationBreakpoint", params: { eventName: "scriptFirstStatement" } }`

Comment: @jenkins Oh that's good to know! Well done. I assume you inspected the DevTools app to find that out.